# Checking if site is available using shell and curl for https URL redirect

Tags: shell, curl, https

I wanted to check if the https://fusionhelp.oracle.com website is available or not. After going through the posts in this site, tried using the `curl` script as shown below on the linux command prompt :

```
curl https://fusionhelp.oracle.com -L -o dumpfile -w 'Last URL was: %{url_effective}'

curl -vi -I -L --cacert FusionhelpRepository https-fusionhelp-website
```

`FusionhelpRepository` contains the security **certificates.pem** merged into one file.

I get `curl`: **(7) socket error: 113** , instead of a status code which would suggest that the website is available. I expect the first response to be **302**, after which it should get redirected to the destination page.

I'm aware that many such posts have been made earlier and the solution works for Yahoo or Google or other HTTPS website which I have been accessing. This one is not going through.

Answer (score 8):

I think you just need the -I option here:

```
curl -I https://fusionhelp.oracle.com
```

This will give the response code, currently showing 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. Its says service unavailable when the website is available. Why do we get that error code and whats the way out to get a 200 code

Comment: Seems to be they are deliberately returning 503 for curl requests - would be my guess at least.